Is this set cover problem NP-complete? (creating a list of best movies per year)
Let $X$ be a finite set. Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a family of subsets of $X$. Assume each set $F\in\mathcal{F}$ is colored with a single color from a set of colors $C$.
Is the following problem NP-complete?
Find $\mathcal{Q}\subset\mathcal{F}$ such that

sets in $\mathcal{Q}$ are disjoint;
no two sets in $\mathcal{Q}$ have the same color;
the colors in $\mathcal{Q}$ are all the colors $C$.

Note that it is the sets in $\mathcal{F}$ themselves that have colors, not the underlying elements of $X$.
Motivation:
This arose from a real problem similar to creating a list of best movies. Can we create a "movie of the year" collection of movies that includes a single movie made from each year, such that no two movies in the list share an actor?

Can you pose this problem as an optimization/decision problem? For example, you may want a $\mathcal{Q}$ of minimal possible cardinality.

https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/54520/5038

@codeR $\mathcal{Q}$ must have the same cardinality as $C$ by definition.

@TLss, right. Then probably your $\mathcal{Q}$ can be thought of as a color class, and hence you can design a reduction from graph coloring.

What have you tried until now? Can you please update the question to include your failed attempts?

@TLss, bipartite matching is poly-time solvable. If your intuition tells you to prove that it is NP-hard, then you should try to reduce it to a known hard problem, such as set-cover, graph coloring, independent set etc.

Hint: You could treat every year as an additional "actor", and the question then becomes to just select a large enough number of movies not sharing any actors.

This problem is NP-complete. The 3-dimensional matching problem can be reduced to this problem.
In a version of the 3-dimensional matching problem, we are given a set of subsets $E \subseteq X \times Y \times Z$ such that $|X| = |Y| = |Z| = k$. The problem is to determine if a subset of edges $F \subseteq E$ exists, such that $|F| = k$ and $\bigcup_{(x, y, z) \in F} \{x,y,z\} = X \cup Y \cup Z$ (a perfect matching for the hypergraph). This problem is known to be NP-hard.
To reduce the problem instance, we let $E$ be the family of subsets, and assign a color $c(e) = x$ to each edge $e = (x, y, z) \in E$. A disjoint subset $Q \subseteq E$ uses all the colors in $X$ if and only if it has size $k$, therefore a perfect 3-dimensional matching.

Thanks for the clear and elegant answer. This method also shows that it is enough that each set in $\mathcal{F}$ has only three elements, which happens to fit better with the motivating real problem as well.

The motivating real problem was closer to this: create an anthology of short stories, one story per year, no two of which share an author. In that formulation, it's more natural to restrict the number of authors per story to some small constant. So you solved that too.
